# Navigation Controller with TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I have a `UIView` which is embedded inside of a `NavigationController`. When the user clicks on a cell in a `TableView` he is taken to the `UIView`. However, the `UIView` pops out from the bottom instead of sliding out from the right side. I have the segue set to *Show*, so I am not sure why it is doing this.

[image]

Comment: Is the TableView Controller *also* embedded in the Navigation Controller?

Comment: It is embedded in a different Navigation Controller.

Comment: That's why it's not working.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new to this. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: On the back button please pop the navigation controller... self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

Answer (score 2):

The slide-in from the side behavior only works when all of the child navigation controllers are children of the *same* UINavigationController. This requirement includes the "root", or first, child. In your case the root child is the UITableViewController.

It will look like this in Storyboard:

UINavVC ---> RootChildVC ---> SecondChildVC ---> ThirdChildVC etc.

A *show* segue is contextual. If it is as in the diagram above, it will be a horizontal slide.

In any other situation at all, including a hand-drawn segue between two arbitrary VCs, a *show* is interpreted as a *modal presentation* which comes in from the bottom and slides back down. You also don't get the automatic "back" button installation because there is no "navigation" relationship detected.

You're probably confused and need to re-do your Storyboard into the above simple idiom. If you're segueing between "cousins" that is VCs whose direct parents are **different** UINavigationControllers, they fall under "any other situation".

Answer (score 0):

A Navigation controller shouldn't be embedded inside another navigation controller.
remove root view relationship between View and NavigationController, delete the NavigationController  and set "show" segue directly from TableView to that view.